# How to remove space between header, main and footer in mobile device mode?

Tags: html, css

This problem is just in mobile mode, the blueviolet line is from background color.

[image]
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04TUW.png)

```css
body {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>this is header</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>this is main</h2>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>this is footer</p>
</footer>
```

Use css reset/normalize css is still not working.

Comment: Start by _not_ checking this at a zoom level of 86% ... most likely these are just rounding issues.

Comment: While emulators can help a lot, it's best to actually check how it looks on a physical device. I've found emulators have display issues and quirks that don't show when testing on an actual iPhone.

Comment: yeah thats right, I tried to deploy it to netlify with the normal settings of margin 0 and padding 0, and I opened it on my phone and the result is that the line is not there, it seems to be only in the browser but the real implementation is still good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add to h1,h2,p margin-top: -1px;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).